# FCM notification not received till app is opened at least once each day

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to build an app where the user would be notified seeking his/her approval. This is a critical aspect of the app. I have configured FCM and I am receiving the notification (I send only data messages) in all three scenarios as mentioned below:

1. When the app is in the foreground
2. When the app is paused and in background
3. When the app is killed(not running)

However my problem starts when I send a notification the following day, the notification does not show up till the app has been opened at least once. I have tried this on three separate physical devices but all have the same behavior. Once the app has been opened, the notifications are received again satisfying all three scenarios mentioned above. I am looking for suggestions on how to debug the issue and what could be causing this kind of behavior. Any pointers would be deeply appreciated.

Given below are the contents of my MyFirebaseMessging class.

````
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    JSONObject jsonObjectRefCode = null;
    String TAG = "DEBUG";
    private String process,firebaseToken;
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "xxxx2" ;
    private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;

    //Will be called when the new token is generated
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        process = "registration";
        firebaseToken = token;
        if(token!=null)
        {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    Constants.registrationURL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            String registration_status;

                            try {
                                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                if(jsonObject.getString("error").equals("false")) {
                                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                                    toast1.show();

                                }else{
                                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                                    toast1.show();

                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error encountered during registering user - "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                            toast1.show();
                        }
                    }){

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("process",process);
                    if(firebaseToken!=null)
                    {
                        params.put("firebase_token", Objects.requireNonNull(firebaseToken.trim()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        params.put("firebase_token", "No firebase token fetched.");
                    }


                    return params;
                }
            };

            NetworkRequestHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        }
    }

    //Will be called when a FCM message is received
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , Activity_Approval. class ) ;
        notificationIntent.putExtra( "NotificationMessage" , "I am from Notification" ) ;
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER ) ;
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN ) ;
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP ) ;

        @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent. getActivity (getApplicationContext() , 0 , notificationIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ) ;

        Bitmap approvalNotificationIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.guard);
        Uri notificationSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small_shield )
                .setLargeIcon(approvalNotificationIcon)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.defaultNotificationColor))
                .setShowWhen(true)
                .setContentTitle( "Visitor Approval Needed" )
                .setContentText( remoteMessage.getData().get("data1")+"Needs your approval to enter the apartment" )
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setFullScreenIntent(resultIntent,true)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                              .bigPicture(approvalNotificationIcon)
                              .bigLargeIcon(null))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent) ;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context. NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION. SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES. O ) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH ;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID , "Approval Notification Channel" , importance) ;
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) ;
            notificationChannel.setSound(notificationSound,audioAttributes);
            mBuilder.setChannelId( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ) ;
            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel) ;
        }
        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mNotificationManager.notify(( int ) System. currentTimeMillis () ,
                mBuilder.build()) ;


        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
}```
````